# How to construct Controller name from route in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying to define a generic route which will handle most of request. Adding a route for each and every feature addition is what I feel not good and not maintainable.

So my target is to write a generic route and resolve the decencies dynamically, which include resolving all dependent controller & service files, resolving templateUrl and resolving controller name. **I can resolve/construct everything except controller name**. Please help me a way around

**My route with a custom resolver:**

```
$routeProvider
 .when('/:module/:controller/:action?', routeResolver.resolve())
```

Inside my custom resolver:

```
function routeResolverProvider(){

this.$get= function(){
  return this;
}

this.resolve = function (options) {
 var route = {};

 route.templateUrl = function (params) {
     var path = String.format('/app/components/{0}/{1}.view.html', params.module, params.controller);
     return path;
 };

 //================================================================================
 route.controller='THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO CONSTRUCT FROM ROUTE as templateUrl'  
 //================================================================================

 route.resolve = {
   loadDependencies: ['$q', '$rootScope', '$route', function ($q, $rootScope, $route) {
      // MY RESOLVE LOGIC HERE
      // I construct dependent file path from route values
      // String.format('/app/components/{0}/{1}.controller.js', params.module, params.controller);
   }]
 };

 return route;
 }}

app.provider('routeResolver', routeResolverProvider)
```

Some good articles:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection
https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c

Comment: `I am trying to define a generic route which will handle most of request` Can't you just use `otherwise`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you want to be able to instantiate a controller by name.

This is possible in AngularJS as explained under [Testing Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#testing-controllers).

You have to use the [`$controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) service like this:

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
$controller('NamedController', {$scope: $scope});
```

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AVCEdLS9zhIzCyZgcXZF?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Dan, I was looking exactly for this kind also. So I modify my resolver as and finally its bingo.

```
this.$get = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$route', '$controller', function () {
    return this;
}];

route.controller = function ($rootScope, $scope, $route, $controller) {
    var params = $route.current.params;
    $controller(params.controller.toLowerCase() + 'Controller', {$scope: $scope});
}
```

Finally I solved my issue but would like to discuss the possible disadvantages of this approach.